# Value initialization of nested structs does not work properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013, initialization

I have this struct definitions:

```
struct inner
{
    int i;
    std::string str;
};

struct outer
{
    inner member[32];
};
```

Now I want to create a value-initialized instance of `outer`, so I write

```
outer o = {};
```

With GCC, this works just fine: all `inner.i` are zeroed and all `inner.str` are empty. But on VS2013, only the `inner.str` are empty; all `inner.i` contain garbage i.e. are not properly initialized.

Without the `std::string` member, the zero-initialization of `inner.i` works with VS2013.

What does the standard say on this? I always assumed `{}` initializes everything, either by zeroing or by calling the default constructor. Am I wrong or is this a very bad bug in VS2013?

Answer (score 2):

This is simply [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members are initialized *by their default initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14)* by empty lists, which performs value-initialization.

Value initialization means that every element of `member` is value-initialized, which in turn means that `i` should be zero.

So yes, this is a VS2013 bug.

Comment: Would be a quite serious bug, right? Initializing stuff is not an exotic use case.

Comment: That compiler often has quite serious bugs in the new features they claim are supported. They still don't have decent variadic templates even though they claimed support for it for three major versions in a row.